# If iOS is a 32 bit OS, how can we be using uint64_t and int64_t?

Tags: ios

It seems to work correctly, but I thought that the most that could be stored in memory was a 32 bit integer?

Now I'm confused as to what difference it makes.

Thanks!

Comment: `int64_t` works on 8-bit computers too.

Comment: @trojanfoe that wasn't very helpful. 4 32-bit floats aren't confusing. That's 4 separate 32-bit memory addresses. uint64_t stores 64-bits together. That's the confusing bit.

Comment: I don't know. That's why I'm asking!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference isn't that you have 64-bit datatypes available to use.  The difference is the size of the memory address space available, and the required size of pointers to memory.  In a 32bit OS you have 2^32 bytes of addressable memory space, and you need 32-bit pointers to cover it all.  In a 64-bit OS you have 2^64 bytes of memory space to address and so pointers must be 64-bit.

At a hardware level, intrinsic 64-bit datatypes may be more optimal on 64-bit hardware since there will be 64-bit registers and instructions to handle them.  Otherwise the compiler/runtime library will be doing more work to support / emulate 64-bit operations on 32-bit hardware.

Comment: I disagree that it's just about the address space available, but also the data registers available (certainly in this case).  Also note that most 64-bit CPUs are only wired-up to address 2^48 bytes.

Comment: So you're saying that although you can only store 32-bit integers in memory, the software "pretends" that you can use 64-bit integers, then just stores them however it can? I think I understand now.

Comment: Sure.  Regardless of 8bit, 16bit, 32bit, 64bit, etc, you can pretty much model anything you want.  If the hardware has native support for an intrinsic data type then so much the better.  But if not then the compiler can fall back on a software implementation.

Answer (score 10):

I think the other answers didn't quite explain this correctly.

uint64_t and int64_t are *C-language data types*, not *hardware* data types.  The compiler does whatever it takes to make these types work as 64-bit unsigned or signed integers.  If the hardware provides 64-bit registers and integer operations then well and good -- the compiler will use those directly.  If the hardware has only 32-bit registers (or 16-bit or 8-bit), the compiler and runtime system use software emulation to get the job done.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What doesn't make sense is what restrictions this has on 32-bit computers? If software can emulate 64-bit integers then why can't software emulate timestamps after 7 Feb 2036 (when the UNIX timestamp overflows 32-bits)?

Comment: Software can emulate timestamps after 2036.  The issue is that the raw data that everything is storing goes into 32 bits, and that is what runs out of space in 2036.  As soon as everything transitions storing dates into 64 bits of storage space that limitation would go away, but remember that a lot of existing code when reading dates from storage is expecting only 32 bits of data.

Comment: The format and amount of storage used for a data item, like timestamps, is typically historical -- it was made a long time ago under different constraints than apply today.  When things like timestamps seem too small it is because storage and processing cycles were both far more scarce in the past and 32-bits seemed "good enough" to last for a while.