# In Swift, what data type should I use to store Integers of 13 digits?

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know anything about 32 bit vs 64 bit (or what any of that means).

I just want to store an integer of 13 digits and use it like every other integer.

- All my integers will be positive, never negative
- Ideally no unnecessary typecasts (but it's okay if it's absolutely necessary)
- I want the data type to be compatible with swift's sort functions
- I'm developing for iOS8

What data type should I use?

Comment: You should always use Int

Comment: @LeoDabus Int can't store 13 digits, right?

Answer (score 1):

`Int64` or `UInt64`. 999... decimal take 44 bits to store so both will be enough for you.

Comment: Can I just use ```UInt``` ??  What's the difference betwee ```UInt``` and ```UInt64```?

Comment: `UInt` is 32-bit on 32-bit hardware (anything below iPhone 5 / iPad Air / iPad Mini 2) and 64-bit on 64-bit hardware. `UInt64` is guaranteed 64-bit everywhere

Comment: If I use ```UInt64```, will I be able to run it on iPhone 4?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_8), the earliest iPhone supported by iOS 8 is iPhone 4S. And yes, you [can use `UInt64` on 32-bit devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140708/if-ios-is-a-32-bit-os-how-can-we-be-using-uint64-t-and-int64-t).